# Change background of v-data-table row on event from child component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an expanding data table in my parent component and a child component inside the expanded row with a button. I would like to change the background color of the associated row when I click the button inside the child component. I'm not sure how to target the row to add the css class on event.

ScanGrid(parent):

```html
    <template>
      <v-flex v-if="items.length === 0">
        <ScanAdd @selectBatch="showScan" />
      </v-flex>
      <v-card v-else class="ma-5">
        <v-card-text>
          <v-layout align-center>
            <v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="items"
              item-key="StorageName"
              show-expand
              single-expand
              :expanded="expanded"
              hide-default-footer
              @click:row="clickedRow"
            >
              <template
                @isDeleted="deleteRow"
                v-if="groupBy === 'barCode'"
                v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }"
              >
                <td :colspan="12">
                  <ScanGridCode :item="item" />
                </td>
              </template>
              <template v-else v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }">
                <td :colspan="12">
                  <ScanGridDef :item="item" />
                </td>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
          </v-layout>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </template>

    <script>
    import { API } from "@/api";
    import ScanAdd from "./ScanAdd";
    import ScanGridCode from "./ScanGridCode";
    import ScanGridDef from "./ScanGridDef";
    export default {
      name: "ScanGrid",
      props: {
        items: {
          type: Array,
          required: true
        }
      },
      components: {
        ScanGridCode,
        ScanGridDef,
        ScanAdd
      },
      methods: {
        deleteRow(value) {
          this.isDeleted = value;
        },
        showScan(value) {
          this.selectedId = value;
          this.addScanBatch(value);
          this.$emit("processingBatch", true);
          this.processingBatch = true;
        },
        async addScanBatch(Id) {
          const selectedItems = await API.getPhysicalInventoryBatch(Id);
          if (selectedItems.data.Id === this.selectedId) {
            this.items = selectedItems.data.Locations;
          }
        },
        clickedRow(value) {
          if (
            this.expanded.length &&
            this.expanded[0].StorageName == value.StorageName
          ) {
            this.expanded = [];
          } else {
            this.expanded = [];
            this.expanded.push(value);
          }
        }
      },
      data: () => ({
        isDeleted: false,
        groupBy: "barCode",
        expanded: [],
        items: [],
        toDelete: "",
        totalResults: 0,
        loading: true,
        headers: [
          {
            text: "Localisation",
            sortable: true,
            value: "StorageName",
            class: "large-column font-weight"
          },
          {
            text: "Paquets scannés",
            sortable: true,
            value: "ScannedProduct",
            class: "large-column font-weight"
          },
          {
            text: "Paquets entrants",
            sortable: true,
            value: "Incoming",
            class: "large-column font-weight"
          },
          {
            text: "Paquets sortants",
            sortable: true,
            value: "Outgoing",
            class: "large-column font-weight"
          },
          {
            text: "Paquets inconnus",
            sortable: true,
            value: "Unknown",
            class: "large-column font-weight"
          }
        ]
      })
    };
    </script>
```

ScanGridCode(child):

```html
    <template>
      <div class="codeContainer">
        <div class="cancelLocation">
          <v-flex class="justify-center">
            <v-btn class="ma-5" large color="lowerCase" tile  @click="deleteLocation"
              >Annuler le dépôt de cette localisation</v-btn
            >
          </v-flex>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: "ScanGridCode",
      props: {
        item: {
          type: Object,
          required: true
        }
      },
      methods: {
        deleteLocation() {
          this.item.IsDeleted = true;
          this.$emit("IsDeleted", true);
        }
      },
      data: () => ({
        IsDeleted: false,
        groupBy: 0,
        headersGroupCode: [
          {
            text: "Code barre",
            sortable: true,
            value: "SerialNumber",
            class: "large-column font-weight-light"
          },
          {
            text: "De",
            sortable: true,
            value: "FromLocation",
            class: "large-column font-weight-light"
          },
          {
            text: "Vers",
            sortable: true,
            value: "ToLocation",
            class: "large-column font-weight-light"
          }
        ]
      })
    };
    </script>
```

I use Vuetify 2.1.7 and Vue 2.6.10. When I click on the button I call deleteLocation function. I assume I need to $emit a value to my parent but after that I don't know how to target the tr to change its style.

Comment: Are you using Vuex?

Comment: Yes I am. Version 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Vuex, I would suggest using some variable such as  `store.state.selectedRow` to keep track of whether or not a row has been selected (or in cases where there are more than one row, which row has been selected).  Then you can have a computed property `myProperty = this.$store.state.selectedRow` in your Vue component which will automatically reflect the single source of truth, and your conditional class can be bound to this `myProperty`.  This means you don't need to worry about emitting on events.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to emitting the event is what should be done. So I am assuming you will emit from deleteLocation function.
Since you need a custom styling on rows you need to add the items slot and add your logic there

```
<template v-slot:item="{ item, select}">
 <tr :class="key === coloredRow ? 'custom-highlight-row' : ''">

     <td :colspan="12">
    <ScanGridCode @changeColor="changeColor(key)" :item="item" />
    </td>
 //add this method to your script element
 changeColor(idx) {
      this.coloredRow = idx;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not using select to expand my row. Also if I define tr in the template the child component in the expanded section only takes the width of the first td, not the whole row. the deleteLocation is where I emit from yes. Also could you be more specific with the code please? Do I declare the style in custom-highlight-row?

Comment: Yes, you can declare styles in any of the class name you have.